# IF statment in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table_changes (Id,stard_date,end_date) and I want to add two columns `rank_end_date` and `new_end_date`.

The problem I have in my data is that not always there is continuousness (in the month level, the day in the month is not in my intrest) between `end_date` and the `start_date` coming just after it (see *example 1*) so I need to "strech" `end_date` in some cases so there will be continuousness at the level of the month.

For *example 1*, the `new_end_date` is `1/2/2015` and doesn't have to be `28/2/2015`.  If the `end_date` in rank 1 is sooner than `31/12/2015` strech it to `31/12/9999`.

Some Examples:

```
Ex1: 
Id   --start date    --end_date    --rank_end_date   new_end_date
111    01/01/1970       1/1/1980         2             1/2/2015 
111    01/03/2015      31/12/9999        1             31/12/9999


 Ex2:
Id   --start_date   --end_date   --rank_end_date   new_end_date 
111   01/01/1970    1/1/1980         1          31/12/9999

Ex3: 
Id   --start_date   --end_date   --rank_end_date   new_end_date 
111   01/01/1970    1/1/1980         2            01/05/1990
111   01/05/1990    31/12/1995       1            31/12/9999

Ex4:
Id --start_date --end_date    --rank__end_date    new_end_date
111 01/03/2015     31/12/9999        1          31/12/9999

Ex5:
Id  --start_Date --end_date     --rank__end_date    new_end_date
111  01/02/2015   31/5/2015             2              01/5/2015
111  01/06/2015   31/12/9999            1              31/12/9999
```

the syntax should be something like this but I don't know how to write those `IF` statements  in `SQL`:

```
if rank_end_date ==2 then new_end_date ==   1/Month(start_date(rank_end_date - 1)) - 1 /2015 
if rank_end_date ==1 then new_end_date  ==  31/12/2015
else new_end_date  = end_date

    Select [Id],[StartDate],[EndDate],
    Rank_End_Date, case 
    when t.Rank_End_Date = (2) **then 
    CAST(CAST(Year([StartDate]) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(Month([StartDate])  AS varchar) + '-' +
--How to do I choose the Start_Date from the record with Rank==1? It is selecting
the start date from the record with rank==2 ofcourse.

     CAST(Day ([EMER_StartDate]) AS varchar) AS DATE) 
    when t.Rank_End_Date = (1) then '9999-12-31'
    else t.[EMER_EndDate] end As New_End_Date
    from  ( 
    Select [Id],[StartDate],[EndDate],
    Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY [Id] order by  [EndDate] desc)  as Rank_End_Date
    from [dbo].[Changes]
    ) t
```

Could anybody help in achieving the result?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server ?

Comment: perhaps it is a gd idea to use SQL procedures.

Comment: You can easily do this with CASE statement which is like if else if else.

Comment: I an using sql-server 2008.

Comment: isagi, but how can I select data from rank 1? 
case when t.Rank_End_Date = 2 then  month(StartDate)+Year(StartDate) Where rank = 1??

Comment: Why don't you create the fields then retrieve all the data to something like php, choose what value you wish to give the new field and execute the query?  Very quick very simple.

Comment: Becasue I need to this on many tables.

Comment: @mox you don't need to be in a sproc context to use `IF`, you can use it in any SQL batch script.

Comment: change the `==` to `=`. This is tsql, not c#...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question right, and you can only have values in rank_end_date of 1 or 2 then something like this query should give you the answer you're looking for. Either way, the LEAD (or LAG function if you sort the records ascending) will allow you to fetch the value from a different record.

```
SELECT ID
     , start_date
     , end_date
     , rank_end_date
     , CASE WHEN rank_end_date = 1 THEN 
            CASE WHEN end_date < '31/12/2005' THEN '31/12/9999' ELSE end_date END
         WHEN rank_end_date = 2 THEN LEAD(start_date,1) OVER(ORDER BY ID, rank_end_date DESC)
       END AS new_end_date          
FROM dbo.Changes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `LEAD` OR `LAG` functions in SQL Server 2008, so you can try this solution.

```
with CTE as
(    
    Select [Id] as ID,[StartDate] as StartDate,[EndDate] as EndDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Id] order by  [StartDate] DESC)  as rn_Start_Date
    from [dbo].[Changes]
)

Select C1.[Id] , C1.[StartDate], C1.[EndDate], C1.rn_Start_Date as Rank_end_date,
       ISNULL(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, C2.[StartDate])-1, 0), cast('9999-12-31' as DATE)) As New_End_Date
From CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.[ID] = C2.[ID] AND C1.Rn_Start_Date = C2.Rn_Start_Date + 1
```